# Error en la inicialización de una variable OpenOPC

Tags: python, windows

estoy intentando inicializar una variable mediante la libreria OpenOPC y no consigo realizarlo. Tras mirar en diferentes foros y diferentes pruebas no he conseguido solucionarlo. Estoy utilizando la versión de 32 bit de python 3.9.7 con la versión de pywin32 (he probado las Build 301, 302 y 303) y siempre reporta el mismo fallo. Lo curioso es que en mi ordenador local he podido ejecutarlo sin problema, el error está cuando realizo los mismos pasos en un equipo concreto. ¿Puede ser algun registro que quede almacenado y que siempre intente ejecutarlo aunque ya no exista esa estructura en el sistema?

Adjunto el código de error de la consola donde se observa concretamente la excepción que obtengo. Esta es la respuesta que obtengo tras introducir `import OpenOPC` y `opc = OpenOPC.client()`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\equipos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 167, in __init__
    self._opc = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(c, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 618, in EnsureDispatch
    disp = win32com.client.Dispatch(prog_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 117, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 106, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 88, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\equipos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 173, in __init__
    raise OPCError(error_msg)
OpenOPC.OPCError: Dispatch: Invalid class string
```

Comment: Hola! Podrías poner el mensaje de error como texto por favor? [Con formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). La respuesta en meta sobre este tema está orientada al código, pero muchos de sus puntos son relevantes también para los mensajes de error: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Answer (score -1):

Visitar esta web para la solución:

https://medium.com/@gabrielveigalima/conectando-opc-da-via-dcom-com-python-3-82f12db75d

Una vez montado los dll, no mover la carpeta de alojamiento.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).